# What is the max video resolution of DELL Studio XPS 16 Webcam

Tags: dell-xps, video-capture

What is the max video (not photo) resolution I can record videos in using the builtin Webcam of the DELL Studio XPS 16?

The Dell page for the XPS 16 states "2.0MP Integrated Webcam", Is that the resolution for videos and photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Dell page](http://www1.euro.dell.com/za/en/dhs/Laptops/laptop-studio-xps-16/pd.aspx?refid=laptop-studio-xps-16&cs=zadhs1&s=dhs) for the [XPS 16](http://hothardware.com/Articles/Dell-Studio-XPS-16-Review/) states "`2.0 MP Integrated Webcam`".

- While this DigitGeek review refers to it as
  "*2.0 MP webcam with nice video capture quality*",
- [Ideas for improved features of future XPS ALL IN ONE](http://www.ideastorm.com/ideaView?id=087700000000LvjAAE) on [this page](http://www.ideastorm.com/ideaList?cat=XPS&lsi=1&p=3vvv) desires
  "*A better quality, high resolution webcam enabling **Hi Def video calls, probably in the line Logitech offers**. Should be partially rotatable/adjustable in order to be able to capture the user. Currently cause webcam is on top of screen, one has to sit up high for the face to be captured entirely*". **Implying**, the existing technology is not really there yet

Comment: Yes I known, but 2 MP is for photos right?

Comment: Hmm, you didn't ask that but, this review says 'nice video capture quality': http://www.digitgeek.com/dell-studio-xps-16-review/

Comment: heh! "high resolution" is marketspeak for "greater than VGA". and technically 480p is a form of HD video. tho note `1080p = 1920x1080 = 2,073,600 =~ 2.0Mega` pixels.

Answer (score 1):

It is rare for webcams to be able to capture very high resolution video:

http://ces.cnet.com/8301-31045_1-10431260-269.html

I suspect this webcam, being a standard bundled type, can probably do 640x480 or 800x600 at most.

Answer (score 1):

It's 1600X1200 for Video on this one.